# SQL SELECT with an exception in a WCF service

Tags: sql, wcf, windows-10-universal

I have a method in the WCF service with a SQL query for a basic log in authentication :

```
SELECT StudentID, Password  
FROM tbUserAccounts 
WHERE StudentID = @ID AND Password = @Password
```

If this query does not find any results, will the WCF encounter this as an error / exception or does it return anything?

The reason I ask is because running this method from my Universal Windows app, I am still able to log in with the password box (which is a textbox) being empty. I must be missing something here since the AND statement is there?

I have a try catch also but it doesn't seem to trigger the catch

Comment: You need to post all of your code, not just the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Query will return a result set with 0 records

You should test for zero results in the result set

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't find any results it will still succeed and return an empty result set.  You probably need to check and make sure that you are getting 1 and only 1 row back.  Also, please don't use this as an actual authentication method for production code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. yes this is pretty basic and I understand this is definitely not the best way to go. I'm only using this as a practice and have an understand of the fundamentals before trying anything else